# React Scoped components Override class

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I am using antd and I wanted to override the select component. However, I am having a problem because it is being applied globally.

Here is my custom css.

customSelect.css

```
.ant-select-single.ant-select-show-arrow .ant-select-selection-item,
.ant-select-single.ant-select-show-arrow .ant-select-selection-placeholder {
  padding: 0;
}
.ant-select-single.ant-select-show-arrow .ant-select-selection-item,
.ant-select-single.ant-select-show-arrow .ant-select-selection-placeholder {
  padding: 0;
}
.ant-select-single.ant-select-show-arrow .ant-select-selection-item,
.ant-select-single.ant-select-show-arrow .ant-select-selection-placeholder {
  font-size: 18px;
}
/* .ant-select-item {
  padding: 0;
} */
.ant-select-single:not(.ant-select-customize-input) .ant-select-selector {
  height: 80px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

I've tried creating a custom component too.

CustomSelect.js

```
import { Select } from 'antd';
import React from 'react';
import './customSelect.css';

export default (props) => {
  return (
    <Select>
    </Select>
  );
};
```

and I want to use it on my component like this

MainComponent.js

```
import { Select } from 'antd';
import React from 'react';
import CustomSelect from '../components/CustomSelect/CustomSelect';
export default (props) => {
  return (
    <Select>
    </Select>
    <CustomSelect>
    </CustomSelect>
  );
};
```

Here is the class I'm trying to access

[image]